# Filter out non-OAuth authenticated sessions via Apache mod_proxy to CouchDB

Tags: apache, oauth, couchdb, mod-proxy

These are my requirements:

1. Apache mod_proxy to make CouchDB available worlwide.
2. couchdb must also be *fully* available on the localhost:5984 port, without authentication.
3. The requests via mod_proxy should *only* be accepted if they are oauth authenticated

Is this at all possible? Can mod_proxy filter out non-OAuth requests?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check: https://github.com/YasuhiroABE/CouchDB-WebProxy_Auth_Handler ?
And in Apache you need to configure the authentication not to forward unauthenticated entries